# Wavelet transform spectrogram in python

Tags: python, wavelet, spectrogram

I am looking for a function to produce spectrograms using wavelet transform in python, something like `pylab.specgram` but using DWT. Does anybody know something like that?

Comment: You mean like PyWavelets? http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/contents.html